# Don't understand what's going wrong with my template design

Tags: jsf

I spend too much time trying to find the problem but i didn't.
I would like to refresh the topbar of my page but while doing what is wrote in other post i get the same behavior in my page :refresh of all the page and sometimes duplication of the datatables.

Here is my code:

Template.xhtml:

```html
 <h:head>
 <title>SI </title>
 <ui:insert name="head" />
 
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <div id="topbar">
  <ui:include src="topbar.xhtml" />
  <ui:debug hotkey="i"/>
 </div>
 <div id="layoutmenu">
 <ui:include src="layoutmenu.xhtml" />
    </div>
 <div id="error">
  <ui:insert name="error">
   <h:form id="formLayout">
    <p:growl id="growl" life="9000" autoUpdate="true" />
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"
     closable="true" width="auto" height="auto"
     styleClass="ui-growl-item-container ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow" />
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dialogWidget" resizable="true" width="100%"
     height="180">
     <p:panel>
      <h:outputLabel value="#{flash.exceptionMessage}" />
     </p:panel>
    </p:dialog>
   </h:form>
  </ui:insert>
 </div>
 <div id="layout-portlets-cover">
  
  <ui:insert name="body">
   <!-- Pages content goes here -->
  </ui:insert>

  <div class="Container100 TexAlCenter Gray FontAdamantiumRegular">
   <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
    All rights reserved.
  </div>
 </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I would like to refresh the included file topbar.xhtml but i cant do it because all the div are refreshed.

in my page.xhtml i have this code:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="subheader">
        Page Header
    </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="head">
  <style>
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
 border: none !important;
}

.ui-panelgrid {
 border: none !important;
}

.ui-timepicker-div {
 background: #f7f5f3;
 border: 1px solid #cecece;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-top: -47px;
 margin-left: 49px;
 margin-right: -75px;
 margin-left: 49px;
}
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>

 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="body">

  <div class="Container100">
   <div class="ContainerIndent">
    <h:form>
     <p:breadCrumb>
      <p:menuitem value="index" url="../../../../index.xhtml" />
      <p:menuitem value="page" url="page.xhtml" />
     </p:breadCrumb>
    </h:form>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divshadow">

   <div class="Container100">
    <div class="ContainerIndent">
     <div class="Card">
      <div class="CardTopic">
       page 
       <h:form>
              content of my page
              </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This project is 5 years old i didn't create this pages but i want to transform it to the right approach .
if someone could help me i would be so gratefull.I spent more than 2 weeks searching the solution and reading posts but i dont find the problem.
thanks

Comment: Try creating a [mcve]. Too much noise...

Comment: thx for your answear.My question is too simple: how to change a content included, by the same file  using another  managed bean.My commadlink calls an action from his controller.
hope this time i ll have an answear .thanks everybody!!